# Adding image to visual editor popup for shortcode with wp.media and wp.mce: changing image duplicates shortcode

Tags: tinymce, visual-editor, media-modal

**tl;dr:** Why does using media manager popup within a TinyMCE popup cause duplications of shortcodes? Is it my code or just the way life is? [Spoiler: It was my code]

I've written a small plugin to create a visual editor button and popup that inserts a shortcode representing a "media object": image to right, text to left.

[image]

In the visual editor you click the button,

[image]

fill in the text in the popup,

[image]

choose the image

[image]

[image]

and hurrah:

[image]

The shortcode is correctly inserted into the editor, and the media view renders it nicely.  (This is a reduced case for this question.  The full popup has a heap of options.)

The only problem I have is if I want to edit the object and change the image.

If I edit the text, things are fine.  If I change the image, then the whole thing inserts a second shortcode instead of replacing the first.

[image]

[image]

I suspect that clicking the Select Image button on the popup is changing the underlying insertion point or selection in the main editor, but I can't for the life of me see how I can fix it.

See here, when I click to edit the object is highlighted:

[image]

Open the popup and the object looks selected still behind:

[image]

(Admin CSS tweaked to make this more visible)

But then clicking the Image button seems to make the selection go:

[image]

Here's my editor view JavaScript, taken from all the work done on shortcode popups by DT Baker a few years ago and still almost the only source of info on the Internet for this.

```
/* global tinyMCE */
(function($){
    var media = wp.media, shortcode_string = 'media_object';
    wp.mce = wp.mce || {};
    wp.mce.media_object = {
        shortcode_data: {},
        template: media.template( 'editor-media-object' ),
        getContent: function() {
            var options = this.shortcode.attrs.named;
            options.innercontent = this.shortcode.content;
            return this.template(options);
        },
        View: { // before WP 4.2:
            template: media.template( 'editor-media-object' ),
            postID: $('#post_ID').val(),
            initialize: function( options ) {
                this.shortcode = options.shortcode;
                wp.mce.media_object.shortcode_data = this.shortcode;
            },
            getHtml: function() {
                var options = this.shortcode.attrs.named;
                options.innercontent = this.shortcode.content;
                return this.template(options);
            }
        },
        edit: function( data ) {
            var shortcode_data = wp.shortcode.next(shortcode_string, data);
            var values = shortcode_data.shortcode.attrs.named;
            // var StrippedString = shortcode_data.shortcode.content.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
            var StrippedString = shortcode_data.shortcode.content.replace(/(<p[^>]+?>|<p>|<\/p>|<br>|<\/br>|<br\/>|<br \/>)/img, "");
            values.innercontent = StrippedString;
            // values.innercontent = shortcode_data.shortcode.content;
            values.imagehtml = '<img src="' + values.image_url + '" class="wp-image-' + values.image_id + '" width=120 height=120 style="max-width: 120px; max-height: 120px;" />';
            wp.mce.media_object.popupwindow(tinyMCE.activeEditor, values);
        },
        // this is called from our tinymce plugin, also can call from our "edit" function above
        // wp.mce.boutique_banner.popupwindow(tinyMCE.activeEditor, "bird");
        popupwindow: function(editor, values, onsubmit_callback){
            values = values || [];
            if(typeof onsubmit_callback !== 'function'){
                onsubmit_callback = function( e ) {
                    // Insert content when the window form is submitted (this also replaces during edit, handy!)
                    var args = {
                            tag     : shortcode_string,
                            //type    : e.data.innercontent.length ? 'closed' : 'single',
                            content : e.data.innercontent,
                            type    : 'closed',
                            //type    : 'single',
                            //content : '',
                            attrs : {
                                image_id    : e.data.image_id,
                                image_url   : e.data.image_url,
                                
                                
                            }
                        };
                    editor.insertContent( wp.shortcode.string( args ) );
                };
            }
            editor.windowManager.open( {
                title: 'Media Object',
                    body: [
                    
                    {
                        type: 'textbox',
                        name: 'innercontent',
                        multiline: true,
                        minWidth: 500,
                        minHeight: 100,
                        label: 'Main Text',
                        value: values.innercontent
                    },
                    
                    
                    {
                        type: 'textbox',
                        name: 'image_url',
                        label: 'Image',
                        id: 'my-image-box',
                        value: values.image_url
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'textbox',
                        name: 'imagehtml',
                        label: '',
                        id: 'my-image-box-html',
                        hidden: true,
                        value: values.imagehtml
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'textbox',
                        name: 'image_id',
                        label: '',
                        id: 'my-image-box-id',
                        hidden: true,
                        value: values.image_id
                    },
                    
{
                    type   : 'container',
                    minWidth: 120,
                    minHeight: 120,
                    
                    name   : 'container',
                    label  : ' ',
                    id: 'my-image-container',
                    html   : values.imagehtml
                },
                
                    {
                        type: 'button',
                        name: 'selectimage',
                        text: 'Select Image',
                        onclick: function() {
                            window.mb = window.mb || {};

                            window.mb.frame = wp.media({
                                frame: 'post',
                                state: 'insert',
                                library : {
                                    type : 'image'
                                },
                                multiple: false
                            });

                            window.mb.frame.on('insert', function() {
                                var json = window.mb.frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

                                if (0 > jQuery.trim(json.url.length)) {
                                    return;
                                }
console.log(json);
                                jQuery('#my-image-box-id').val(json.id);
                                jQuery('#my-image-box').val(json.sizes.medium.url);
                                //jQuery('#my-image-container').prepend('<img src="' + json.url + '" />');
                                jQuery('#my-image-container-body').empty().prepend('<img src="' + json.sizes.medium.url + '" width=120 height=120 style="max-width: 120px; max-height: 120px;" />');
                                imagehtml = '<img src="' + json.sizes.medium.url + '" class="wp-image-' + json.id + '" />';
                                jQuery('#my-image-box-html').val(imagehtml);
                            });

                            window.mb.frame.open();
                        }
                    }],
                onsubmit: onsubmit_callback
            } );
        }
    };
    wp.mce.views.register( shortcode_string, wp.mce.media_object );
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suspect that clicking the Select Image button on the popup is
> changing the underlying insertion point or selection in the main
> editor, but I can't for the life of me see how I can fix it.

I'm afraid I don't know *why exactly* the issue happens only when the image is changed, but I can tell you the issue is with your `popupwindow()` function which always calls `editor.insertContent()` (where `editor` is `tinyMCE.activeEditor`).

And the proper way to set the content/shortcode is, or here's how can you fix the issue: Use `editor.insertContent()` when adding the shortcode, whereas when editing it (e.g. changing the "Main Text" or the image), you should use the `update()` function that's passed to your `edit()` function.

So firstly, define that function like so, and then pass the `update` to `popupwindow()`:

**Note:** The `your code here` means your original code (i.e. no changes).

```js
// 1. Add the "update" parameter.
edit: function( data, update ) {
    // ... your code here (define shortcode_data, etc).

    // 2. Pass the "update" to popupwindow().
    wp.mce.media_object.popupwindow( tinyMCE.activeEditor, values, update );
},
```

And then define the `popupwindow()` and `onsubmit_callback()` functions like so:

```js
// 1. Add the "update" parameter.
popupwindow: function( editor, values, update ) {
    values = values || [];

    var onsubmit_callback = function( e ) {
        // ... your code here (define "args", etc).

        // 2. Use the "update" function, if available.
        if ( update ) { // the shortcode already in the content and is being edited
            update( wp.shortcode.string( args ) );
        } else { // the shortcode is being added for the 1st time
            editor.insertContent( wp.shortcode.string( args ) );
        }
    };

    editor.windowManager.open( /* your code here */ );
}
```

So I hope that helps and actually, in your code, you could just use `$` instead of `jQuery`, e.g. `$('#my-image-box-id').val(json.id)`. =)

Comment: I’m jumping between deadlines so will get back on this after but that all makes sense!

Comment: I was so excited I had to try it out. Sadly this doesn't fix it.  I'm adding something I've seen to the question though.

Comment: Could you please post on Pastebin (or somewhere else) your JS script after you applied the changes mentioned in my answer? Are you using WordPress 5.7?

Comment: Sure: https://pastebin.com/AQgcQm7q

Comment: You forgot the first step as shown in my answer, i.e. you forgot to change the `edit()` function. So referring to that [Paste](https://pastebin.com/AQgcQm7q), in line 26, it should be `edit: function( data, update )` and in line 34, it should be `wp.mce.media_object.popupwindow(tinyMCE.activeEditor, values, update);`. Please make these changes and check again.

Comment: Oh my.  Yes, that was clumsy of me, and yes it now appears to work! That's amazing, thank you.  I'm going to just test a little more, but looks like the bounty will be yours.

Comment: And the designer I do most of my development for is really pleased and wants me to pass on his thanks too.

Comment: You're very welcome and thanks for the bounty! 

Comment: No problem.  Did you get it OK?  Stack keeps sending me reminders to award it.

Comment: Yes I did! Thanks again :)